Principal value integral of $f(x)/x^2$
I wish to compute the principal value integral,
\begin{align}
I = PV \int_{-u}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-(u+s)^2}e^{-i\Omega s}}{s^2} ds
\end{align}
Splitting the integrand up, we get,
\begin{align}
I &= \underbrace{ PV \int_0^u \frac{e^{-(u-s)^2}e^{i\Omega s}}{s^2}ds }_{I_1} \underbrace{ + PV\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-(u+s)^2}e^{-i\Omega s}}{s^2}ds}_{I_2}
\end{align}
Using the Hadamard regularisation I simplified $I_1$ and $I_2$ to,
\begin{align}
I_1 &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg[ \int_{\epsilon}^u \frac{e^{-(u-s)^2}e^{i\Omega s}}{s^2} - \frac{e^{-(u-\epsilon)^2}e^{i\Omega\epsilon}+e^{-(u+\epsilon)^2}e^{-i\Omega\epsilon}}{\epsilon} \bigg] 
\\
I_2 &= \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \bigg[\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-(u+s)^2}e^{-i\Omega s}}{s^2} - \frac{e^{-(u+\epsilon)^2}e^{-i\Omega\epsilon}+e^{-(u-\epsilon)^2}e^{i\Omega\epsilon}}{\epsilon} \bigg] 
\end{align}
Would appreciate if someone had pointers on how to compute the two integrals in the brackets, or if there is a more efficient way to compute $I$ in the first place. Or is there a more concise application of distribution theory to an integral of the form of $I$? For example I have seen a result:
\begin{align}
 J &= PV \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{f(s)}{s^2} ds = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{f(s)+f(-s)-2f(0)}{s^2}
\end{align}
Could such a result be generalised to finite bounds as per my integral $I$?
PS. I am a physicist.

I can't solve it, but Mathematica can. Are you interested in what the machine says?

Haha, as long as it is not $10^{157}$! -- I have not worked with Mathematica's PV functions in much depth...

With permission from OP, posting an answer that is mostly the job of Mathematica, with very little of my work...
My steps before asking Mathematica:
$$
\begin{align}
I & = \int\limits_{-u}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(s+u)^2}}{s^2} e^{-i \Omega s} ds \\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(s+u)^2} \theta(s+u)}{s^2} e^{-i \Omega s} ds \text{  ,where } \theta \text{ is Heaviside function}  \\
& = \mathcal{F}_{s}\left\{ \frac{e^{-(s+u)^2} \theta(s+u)}{s^2} \right\}(\Omega) \text{  , where } \mathcal{F} \text{ is Fourier Transform } \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \mathcal{F}_{s}\left\{ e^{-(s+u)^2} \theta(s+u) \right\}(y) \star \mathcal{F}_{s}\left\{ \frac{1}{s^2} \right\}(y) \right)(\Omega) \text{  ,where} \star \text{ is convolution } \\
\end{align}
$$
Now on everything is from Mathematica:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_{s}\left\{ e^{-(s+u)^2} \theta(s+u) \right\}(y) & = \frac{1}{2} e^{i u y - \frac{y^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi} \left[1 - i \operatorname{Erfi}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \right] \\
\\
\mathcal{F}_{s}\left\{ \frac{1}{s^2} \right\}(y) & = -\pi y \operatorname{Sign}(y) \\
\end{align}
$$
After convolution,
$$
I = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[-\frac{2(\pi+\pi^{\frac32}u)}{u} + \\
e^{-u^2} \pi (2u + i \Omega) \left\{ \operatorname{CoshIntegral}(u^2) + \pi \operatorname{Erfi}(u)  + \operatorname{SinhIntegral}(u^2)\right\}    \right]
$$
For reference, CoshIntegral and SinhIntegral
If you are unfamiliar with CoshIntegral and SinhIntegral, but are familiar with Cos Integral and Sine Integral, better looking formulas are:
$$\operatorname{Chi}(x) = \operatorname{Ci}(i x) + \log(x) - \log(i x)$$
$$\operatorname{Shi}(x) = -i \operatorname{Si}(i x)$$
